# Discord.js Autocomplete not showing choices

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm using Discord.js v14 to implement autocomplete function for my Discord bot. I mostly followed this guide:

https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/autocomplete.html#sending-results

Autocomplete is triggered for the `/character` command, but whatever I type, there are no choices (and I wrote 2 choices in the code, following the guide).

Other commands that are not using autocomplete work fine.

The bot has the following permissions: Read Messages/View Channels, Send Messages, Embed Links, Attach Files, and Use Slash Commands.

command `character.js` (execute part is just currently a placeholder):

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { ref, child, get } = require('firebase/database');
const { db, dbref } = require('..');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('character')
    .setDescription('Choose a Character')
    .addStringOption(option =>
        option.setName('character-name')
        .setDescription('Name of the Character')
        .setAutocomplete(true)),
    async autocomplete(interaction) {
        const focusedValue = interaction.options.getFocused();
        const choices = ['option', 'choice'];
        const filtered = choices.filter(choice => choice.startsWith(focusedValue));
        await interaction.respond(
            filtered.map((choice) => ({ name: choice, value: choice })),
        )
    },
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply(interaction.options.getString("character-name"));
    },
};
```

File: `interactionCreate.js`

```
const { Events, InteractionType } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.InteractionCreate,
    async execute(interaction) {
        if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

        if(interaction.type == InteractionType.ApplicationCommand){
            const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

            if (!command) {
                console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
                return;
            }
    
            try {
                await command.execute(interaction);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Error executing ${interaction.commandName}`);
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
        else if(interaction.isAutocomplete()){
            const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

            if(!command) {
                console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
                return;
            }

            try{
                await command.autocomplete(interaction);
            } catch(error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }

    },
};
```

If you need more info, feel free to write in the comments. I'm not sure what the problem is, so I don't know info you may need.

I've also tried:

```
const { Events, InteractionType } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.InteractionCreate,
    async execute(interaction) {
        if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
        
        if(interaction.type == InteractionType.ApplicationCommand){
            const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

            if (!command) {
                console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
                return;
            }
    
            try {
                await command.execute(interaction);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Error executing ${interaction.commandName}`);
                console.error(error);
            }


            if(interaction.isAutocomplete()){
    
                if(!command) {
                    console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
                    return;
                }
    
                try{
                    await command.autocomplete(interaction);
                } catch(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            }

        }




    },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top you have a typeguard, preventing you from responding to autocomplete interactions

```js
if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
```

You should remove this, so it can run for interactions which are not chat input commands.

Comment: I thought this is something else. I left it from one of the previous tutorial sections. I thought that chatInputCommand is when you use commands with a custom prefix. Thank you! It's working.